# CP2102 device is not listed in /dev on macOS 13.5 M1 Chip

Tags: macos

I currently have a WROOM ESP32 Board with a silicon Labs CP2012 controller. I installed the driver from the official website. (https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers?tab=downloads). I cant seem to find the driver downloaded anywhere in the /dev/ folder nor do i get the UART TO USB port to connect my esp32 to my arduino ide. When i downloaded the driver, i pressed allow in the security and privacy setting when it prompted it to me

Comment: Are you certain that the drivers are for available for Apple Silicon/ARM architecture?  I did a quick look and nowhere does it say ARM compatible.  You need to check with SiliconLabs to confirm.

Comment: I meet the same problem. I guess CP2102 driver does not support the lastest macOS 13.5 version. No way to solve